# how to redirect output from cd in a shell written in C

Tags: c, linux, shell

I m writing a basic shell in C, I have all the redirect operators implemented, however, when I try to redirect "cd" I run into this problem :

cd works perfectly without any output redirection, but

when I m trying to do something like this :

```
cd inexistant_directory > output_file
```

the output file is not created, in bash, running that command does redirect the stdout, as I previously stated redirection operators with external commands work good

when I encounter cd command, I call

```
char*path = get_path(parameters);  //implemented by me, works on rest of the cases
int  ret =chdir(path);
```

I don't call this in the child process but in parent(shell process itself)

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you,

PS : The OS on which I run this is Ubuntu 12.10 however, the code is POSIX compliant

LE: I can't post the whole code as it goes to around 600 lines,

here's my logic tho

```
if(internal_command) {
     //do quit, exit or cd
} else if (variable_assignemt){
     //do stuff
} else {
    // external command
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1) {
        //crash
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        do_redirects()
        call_external_cmd
     }
    default : 
        wait(pid, &status);
```

So, I think that to solve the issue I need to redirect stdout in parrent(shell process)
and restore it after command is executed

Comment: what is the output you get?

Comment: Show more of the code of your shell. It probably has bugs.

Comment: The redirect in the shell does a `dup2` or `dup` system call usually to redirect `STDOUT` to another file descriptor which would be the output file in this case.

Comment: Well... If you didn't implement this functionality in your shell, why do you expect it to work?

Comment: @Jake223 I don't get any output, there is simply no created file.

Comment: If get_path doesn't know how to do output redirection, I wouldn't expect there to be one.

Comment: yes, that's the problem, I think, I am doing all my redirections in the child, so I will need to redirect and restore stdout in parent aswell

Answer (score 0):

Not redirecting stdout in parent process (shell) was indeed the cause of 
cd's unwanted behaviour, my solution was the following:

```
   if(we_have_out_redirection == 1) {
       if(out != NULL) {

       char *outParrent = out;

           fflush(stdout);

       outBackup = dup(STDOUT_FILENO); //I save stdout for future restoration
       int fd = open(outParrent, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644); //open output file
       int rc;
           rc = dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO); //redirect stdout

    retval = chdir(out); //execute cd command

        //restore stdout
    close(fd); 
    fflush(stdout);
    rc = dup2(outBackup, 1);
    close(outBackup);
   }
}
```

Thanks to Jake223 for pointing out I forgot to redirect in parrent !